# django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, testing

I have error like in title when I'm trying to run test, I dont know whats going on but my testUser doesn't work properly, It's funny because i have identical test user in another project and there everything is ok.

## test_api.py

```
class TaskDetailViewAPI(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.client = APIClient()
       self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='test123')
       self.user.save()

   @classmethod
   def setUpTestData(cls):
       user = User.objects.get(id=1)
       Task.objects.create(name='TestTask', user=user, status='NEW', date=date(2019, 4, 9), description='This is test')

    def test_access_to_view_logged(self):
       task= Task.objects.get(id=1)
       login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test123')
       self.assertTrue(login)
```

And this is test from another project where everything works fine

```
class CreateCommentAPI(APITestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.client = APIClient()
       self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='test123')
       self.user.save()

   @classmethod
   def setUpTestData(cls):
       Category.objects.create(name='PC', slug='pc')
       Product.objects.create(
           category=Category.objects.get(id=1),
           name='Laptop', slug='laptop',
           description='here is description',
           photo=SimpleUploadedFile("file.jpeg", b"file_content", content_type="image/jpeg"),
           price=1999, available='available'
        )

   def test_access_to_view_logged(self):
       product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
       login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test123')
       response = self.client.get(reverse('add_comments', kwargs={'id': product.id}))
       self.assertTrue(login)
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, f'expected Response code 200, instead get {response.status_code}')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setUpTestData` is called only once for the whole test class, but more importantly it is called *before* `setUp`.

Your working code doesn't have anything inside `setUpTestData` that depends on data in `setUp`, which is correct. But your non-working code *does*; it tries to access the User, which hasn't been created yet. You need to refactor things so that the User is either created inside `setUpTestData`, or the Task is created inside `setUp`.

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that creating user inside setUpTestData works, This is correct answer so I will accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Your test user's id might not be 1, instead of using the id, you could use the username in your `setUpTestData` method:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='test')
```

Comment: Yes, but this fragment isnt for login purpose, and in my code i have problem that login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test123') != True

Comment: The `DoesNotExist` exception in your title is most likely to come from a `get()` call. If your code failed the test then it should throw an `AssertionError` or simply get a failed test message.

Comment: Change not helped but I see that when i delete def setUpTestData(cls): then login == True

Comment: Now, I'm sure that problem is with setUpTestData, but change user to user = User.objects.get(username='test') didn't help, ok I will look whats is wrong with my test object, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: In my case, I forgot to create and apply the migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Longer, I have modified Django models, but did not push/migrate the changes into the database, which actually holds the data about those models. So when my code asked for the model data, they were not in the DB, thus the `matching query does not exist`.

This is not the case for the OPs question, although my answer could be a solution to the error mentioned in the title, which got me here in the first place.